# Where is Node.js own dependencies (V8, libuv) located locally?

Tags: c++, node.js, web-development-server

I looked at Node.js's documentation:

> "Node.js includes a number of other statically linked libraries including OpenSSL. These other libraries are located in the deps/ directory in the Node.js source tree."

I installed Node.js and check out the directory Program files/nodejs, but I cannot find the deps/directory? Where is V8, libuv being stored in my local files?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/deps

Comment: But this directory does not appear in my computer's local files?

Comment: Because it is embedded in the node executable file.

Comment: what do you mean by embedding in the node.exe? I am totally new to programming

Comment: They are static libraries. Static libraries' code is included in the exe (linked) when the node.js is compiled from its source code to generate it (the exe).

Comment: This stuff is compiled into the nodejs executable.  You won't separately find it in your file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node is a program where its C/C++, static libraries it uses (such as libuv) and various other resources it uses are compiled into `node.exe` (on Windows).  So, the things you're asking about are inside of node.exe.

They are not separately available in your file system when you just install the runnable version of nodejs.

If you cloned the source repository and built it yourself, you'd have all the components in your local source repository that are then compiled into node.exe.  But, if you install an already built version of nodejs, then you will just get the binary executable files that already have the components built into them.